# solrindex way of mapping nutch schema to solr

Tags: solr, nutch

We have several custom nutch fields that the crawler picks up and indexes. Transferring this to solr via solrindex (using the mapping file) works fine. The log shows everything is fine, however the index in solr environment does not reflect this. 
Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is use a tool like [tcpmon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/) to monitor exactly what Nutch is sending to Solr. By examing the xml payload, you could determine if Nutch is correctly sending those custom fields to Solr. If Nutch is sending them correctly, there is something going on on the Solr side. On the opposite, re-check your Nutch code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Pascal. I did as you suggested and realized that only core and plugin fields were part of the incoming NutchDocument that was being mapped. I realize my issue was that I was using another installation of nutch which didn't have the plugins that added the custom fields to nutch index. So I am sure with the original 'crawled' installation, the solr index would have the additional custom fields too. Hope this helps someone. Thank you again.